# Jade compiling in one line

Tags: gulp

My problem is that while I'm compiling Jade in gulp some tags in HTML end up on the same line. 
For exmaple  this [image]  ends up like this  [image]
I want it look something like that. Is is possible?  [image]
  Here is my gulpfile

```
gulp.task('templates', function() {
  var YOUR_LOCALS = {};

  gulp.src('./*.jade')
    .pipe(jade({
      pretty: true,
      locals: YOUR_LOCALS
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most HTML prettifiers will not place inline elements like `<span>` or `<i>` on their own line by default. The good ones will let you overwrite that default behavior however. Seems like there is no way to do that with Jade's built-in `pretty` option.

That means you will have to use an external HTML prettifier like [`gulp-prettify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-prettify). It's based on [`js-beautify`](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify) which has [a whole plethora of options](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify#css--html) that let you influence the way your HTML is formatted.

Among those the `unformatted` option determines which elements will not be indented on their own line. Again by default this includes all inline elements. Passing an empty list instead disables that behavior:

```
var prettify = require('gulp-prettify');

gulp.task('templates', function() {
  var YOUR_LOCALS = {};

  gulp.src('./*.jade')
    .pipe(jade({
      locals: YOUR_LOCALS
    }))
    .pipe(prettify({
      unformatted: []
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```